# Import multiple lines of data for object in txt. file

Tags: java, file, oop, import, readfile

I am currently trying to create a small quiz application in which the object class will contain:

- question
- answerChoice1
- answerChoice2
- answerChoice3
- correctAnswerNum

To contain the this data I have a txt. file that contains the relevant data. That file is also in the same formatting as the list above.

What I would like to do is read the file and import the data from each line and convert for my program to use.

This differs from other questions of this nature as I am looking to convert the question (of which there will be spaces in the string) while also importing other object data for the same object set in the array on separate lines.

```
questions (String question, String answer1, String answer2, String answer3, int correctAnswer){
    this.question = question;
    this.answer1 = answer1;
    this.answer2 = answer2;
    this.answer3 = answer3;
    this.correctAnswer = correctAnswer;
}

public String getQuestion(){
    return question;
}

public String getAnswer1(){
    return answer1;
}

public String getAnswer2(){
    return answer2;
}

public String getAnswer3(){
    return answer3;
}

public int getCorrectAnswer(){
    return correctAnswer;
}
```

Here is my object class at the moment, if needed.

Comment: Is it an assignment you'd like somebody complete for you? for free? Show what you did to read that file and where is a problem?

Comment: No. Its a revision tool I'm trying to make to prepare for my exams, and I thought it was already clear that I don't know how to approach my problem.  If you don't know how to help then why bother commenting? It just made you look like more an arse than me and my most basic programming capabilities.

Comment: "What I would like to do is read the file" - so, what did you do to read the file? what problem you have with your code?...  "and import the data from each line" - what did you do to import data from each line? and so on...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may implement Serializable interface in your class. This is an interface-marker, so it doesn't contain any methods and fields. Classes that do not implement this interface will not have any of their state serialized or deserialized.
You have to must implement special methods with these exact signatures:

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException
private void readObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException;
private void readObjectNoData() throws ObjectStreamException;
```

So, your "writeObject()" method will be like this:

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectOutputStream out) throws IOException {
    out.writeString(question);
    out.writeString(answer1);
    out.writeString(answer2);
    out.writeString(answer3);
    out.writeInt(correctAnswer);
}
```

And your "readObject" will be like this:

```
private void writeObject(java.io.ObjectInputStream in) throws IOException,ClassNotFoundException {
        question = in.readString();
        answer1 = in.readString();
        answer2 = in.readString();
        answer3 = in.readString();
        correctAnswer = in.readInt();
    }
```